# How to change product id?

Tags: magento-1.8

I just want to change the product id, as i want it to be continuous. I have IDs in the following order `1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 16, 17`
 So I want to change `16` and `17` back to `11` and `12` respectively. This discontinuity must be appearing because I had deleted some products. So How to change product ID? by any method

**Update:** I tried deleting the items on top and registering it again but now it starts from `18` :P

Comment: http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/how-to-remove-all-catalog-products-in-magento/
try this one

Comment: @KeyulShah I do not want to remove all of them... i just want to id them properly(continuous)

Answer (score 5):

This is a really bad idea which is going to cause you huge amounts of headaches in future.

The records in `sales_flat_order_item` table store all product sales history refering to the products respectively in the `product_id` field. If you re-use product IDs, your table is going to make very little sense and generating sales reports is going to be horrendous.

Just stick to the default functionality in my opinion.

**If regardless of this you decide you want to do it, don't say I didn't warn you:**

Access the database using something like PHPMyAdmin and go to the `catalog_product_entity` table, find the products you wish to update and manually change their value in the `entity_id` field, this corresponds to `product_id`.

Comment: It may not be as bad as you say, because there are constraints defined. I'll have to look if they're all there, but at the very least you should do a reindex after this operation. Extensions though, is a whole different can of worms.